# IllegalStateException in a SSL connection, performing a SAML login?

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, saml

I'm implementing a little snippet of code in order to log into a SAML protected website.

I have this piece of code:

```
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
```

through which I connect with a safe SSL connection to some URLs.
On the first two times, with two different URLs, it works perfectly, but then, when I try to perform a specific request (the SAMLRequest to the IDP server, to be precise), the script thows this error:

```
[ATTENTION] An error occured: java.lang.IllegalStateException: connection not yet open
```

I can't really understand what's going on. While connecting to the SP, the connection is good (I also able to obtain this information, so I suppose the SSL to be working `con.getCipherSuite() = TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA`), but then it stops.

Since the request I'm trying to issue is the only one which really matters in the SAML scheme, among the three I tried to perform, I thought it was a server-side problem:

```
Connect to the homepage of the service provider (SP) in order to get JSESSIONID cookie: it works
Connect to the SP login page in order to get the SAML Request: it works
Connect to the IDP in order to send (via GET) the SAML Request: ERROR.
```

How can I get rid of this problem, and be sure the connection is safe? I have the *strong* need to avoid a MINM attack, since the script will be implemented in an Android app which will need a strong level of security...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I might be a bit off topic here!
Are you using Google app engine for this? As google app engine doesn't support HttpsUrlConnection. Please read more [here](http://esxx.blogspot.fr/2009/06/using-apaches-httpclient-on-google-app.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't aware of it. Is there something analogue for Android?

Comment: Not very sure, not a Andriod developer